# smack is connecting to ejabberd server

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, smack

Here is my smack code to connect ejabberd server

```
    XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.Builder builder = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder();
    builder.setUsernameAndPassword("admin@manish-lenovo-g510", "admin");
    builder.setServiceName("manish-lenovo-g510");
    builder.setHost("192.168.1.2");     
    builder.setPort(5280);
    XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration build = builder.build();        
    AbstractXMPPConnection conn1 = new XMPPTCPConnection(build);
    conn1.connect();
```

I am getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$NoResponseException: No response received within reply timeout. Timeout was 5000ms (~5s). Used filter: No filter used or filter was 'null'.
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$NoResponseException.newWith(SmackException.java:106)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$NoResponseException.newWith(SmackException.java:85)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.SynchronizationPoint.checkForResponse(SynchronizationPoint.java:253)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.SynchronizationPoint.checkIfSuccessOrWait(SynchronizationPoint.java:146)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.SynchronizationPoint.checkIfSuccessOrWaitOrThrow(SynchronizationPoint.java:125)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection.connectInternal(XMPPTCPConnection.java:837)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.AbstractXMPPConnection.connect(AbstractXMPPConnection.java:365)
```

if i open admin interface of ejabberd its opening so Why this code is not working. One more thing how to find the service name as i guess that might be the issue as i dont know the service name, i have given it randomly.

Answer (score 2):

I think port should be the standard XMPP port which is 5222. 5280 is the port for web admin, which speaks HTTP, not XMPP.

Comment: what about the service name ? how will know the service name ?

Comment: It depends of the configuration of your server. Look at the host for example.

Comment: in `ejabberd.yaml` i found 'hosts` field. is that what you are talking about ? it is something like `hosts:
  - "manish-Vostro-2520"` on my local pc

Comment: So that's your domain name, yes. Domain is at the core of the XMPP protocol.